# How to set "tabs only"-policy for XML-files in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tabs

Is it somehow possible to set a tabs-only policy for the XML-Editor in eclipse?

For Java-files it can be done in a profile under:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
```

but this only affects Java-files and not XML-files. Under

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text-Editors
```

it does not seem to be possible,...

Comment: Did you try `Window->Preferences->XML->XML Files->Editor->Indent using tabs` ?

Comment: Is already checked. One thing that's not working, is `Ctrl+i` to correct the indentation (i.e. replace 4 spaces by a tab).

Comment: For this you should use <ctrl>+<shift>+<F> to format. In my eclipse (luna), all spaces are replaced by tabs, when the file is opened in the xml editor.

Comment: @Cfx Could you please put your comments into an answer. I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure, `Window->Preferences->XML->XML Files->Editor->Indent using tabs` checkbox is checked
2. Open the file with XML editor `rightclick->Open with->XML Editor`
3. To replace all spaces with tabs, press `<ctrl>+<shift>+<F>`